# Aegir content types extra fields

Tags: aegir

Is there an official way to add extra fields on a content type on Aegir.
To be more accurate, I want to a comment (text) field for the 'sites'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Drupal, so yes you can add an extra field to the site content type on `/admin/structure/types/manage/site/fields`.

Warning: you must enable first the `field_ui` module, as it's disabled by default in Aegir installation profile.

I started a documentation page about this: http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/extend/frontend/

Comment: It doesn't work on Aegir. I tested it before.

Comment: Do you have the core field_ui module enabled?

Comment: Lame... I feel so stupid! Thnx mate! (omg..)